# After uninstalling Media Player Classic some shortcuts are left behind

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, uninstall, maintenance

I uninstalled Media Player Classic but some short cuts are left behind that don't work anymore. For example the "Play Video" option when the external hard drive is shown is now invalid. How can I remove these obsolete links/shortcuts etc.?
[image: Play video missing application]

Comment: I would try installing and removing the program again to see if it was a simple gltich. If it happens again report to the bug to the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the registry entries for that Autoplay handler:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers\<handler_name>

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers\<event_name>
```